# using HTA with batch file

Tags: batch-file, hta

I have created HTA file which has userform to collect data from the user.
I am calling this HTA file from batch file.

After reading user inputs, i want input values to be passed to batch file from HTA.
Is is possible to achieve?

Comment: is it a problem to save and read them into a file?

Comment: I did in the same way you have told. Its working. THank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can have the HTA file return the values to the batch file, but it cannot do it directly.  You have to use Javascript to create a text file with the user provided values, then your batch file can process the values.  Here's a site with several methods listed to read and write text files:

http://www.c-point.com/JavaScript/articles/file_access_with_JavaScript.htm

Using one of these, I created a very simple example to demonstrate how this is done:

SimpleForm.hta

```
<HTML> 
  <HEAD> 
    <SCRIPT language="JavaScript">
      function WriteFile() {
        var fso  = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"); 
        var fh = fso.CreateTextFile("c:\\Output.txt", true); 
        fh.WriteLine(myForm.FN.value + '~' + myForm.LN.value);
        fh.Close(); 
      }
    </SCRIPT>
  </HEAD>
  <BODY>
    <FORM name="myForm">
      <P>First Name: <INPUT name="FN" type="text"></P>
      <P>Last Name: <INPUT name="LN" type="text"></P>
      <P><INPUT type="button" value="Save Values" onclick="WriteFile();"></P>
    </FORM>
    <P>After you click 'save', close the window.</P>
  </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Now the batch file:

```
@echo off

start /wait SimpleForm.hta
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=~" %%i in (C:\Output.txt) do (
  set FirstName=%%i
  set LastName=%%j
)

del C:\Output.txt

echo The user entered %FirstName% %LastName% for their name.
```

You will need to deal with the complexities of the user typing in the delimiter character (a tilde in my example) into one of the text fields and throwing off parameter parsing of the `for` statement.  You could use an obscure character that the user won't type for instance.