# Opening Google in Javascript

Tags: javascript, batch-file

I'm trying to make a simple programme that opens google chrome here is what I have:

```
function launch(){
    var website = document.getElementById("input1").value;
    var instances = document.getElementById("input2").value;
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < instances; i++) {
        // INSERT COMMAND HERE##    
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is you input a website url which is set as the variable website and a number which is set as the variable instances. I then want it to loop the command of opening google chrome with the website how ever many times the variable instances is set to, however each loop it opens a different person eg: person 1, person 2 ect... To do that I will use the variable i

Basically I need to be able to do this from batch but on Javascript:

```
set /p website=[1] Website URL: 
set /p instances=[2] Instances: 
for /l %%a in (1,1,%instances%) do ( start chrome --profile-directory="Profile %%a" -open %website% )
```

Here is the full code:

```
<!-- :: Batch section
@echo off
setlocal
if not defined flag set "flag=1" & start "HTA" /MIN "%~F0" & goto :EOF
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('mshta.exe "%~F0"') do set "HTAreply=%%a"
echo End of HTA window, reply: "%HTAreply%"
exit
-->
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<HTA:APPLICATION SCROLL="no" SYSMENU="no" >

<TITLE>Website Opener</TITLE>
<SCRIPT language="JavaScript">
window.resizeTo(340,160);

function closeHTA(reply){
    var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    fso.GetStandardStream(1).WriteLine(reply);
    window.close();
}
function launch(){
    var website = document.getElementById("input1").value;
    var instances = document.getElementById("input2").value;
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < instances; i++) {
    // INSERT COMMAND HERE
    }
}
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
    <div class="text1">
    Website: <input type="text" id="input1" value=""/>
    </div>
    <div class="text1">
    Instances: <input type="text" id="input2" value=""/>
    </div>
    <p>
    </p>
    <div>
    <button onclick="closeHTA(1)">Close</button>
    &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
    <button onclick="launch();">Open Profiles</button>
    </div>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: I just need it to open chrome instances on a website but on different profiles eg: Person 1, Person 2 and so on

Comment: On batch it's --profile-directory="profile name"

Comment: Well, assuming he is not talking about running js in the browser it is possible. Node can spawn new processes

Comment: Basically its a batch file that creates a GUI then uses html and js for the functions

Comment: I'm not running in a browser, its a batch file that uses batch-hta along side html to create a GUI, then it uses JS for functions and commands

Comment: Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14826682/using-hta-with-batch-file